# SSL certificates error with godaddy domain and cloudflare certificates

Tags: ssl, heroku, cloudflare

I'm new to web development and finally been able to create something and show to the world. I have the domain with godaddy, hosted webapp with heroku and using cloudflare SSL certificates. Trying to be cheap as dont want to spend money until I find some traffic to the website.

Chrome and Firefox warn that website is not safe when I type

> www.mywebsite.com

however When I type

> https://www.mywebsite.com

they work fine. Interestingly I also tested website on opera and it does not warn me at all and successfully show the valid certificates. Can anyone please help?

Comment: We can't figure this out unless you give the true url.

Comment: Sorry, here is the website www.aircargoexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

That is just showing you that you are accessing the site not in SSL (https). You should put in an automatic redirect to avoid people seeing that.

Comment: Thanks could you please elaborate why and how to redirect people to SSL (https). Thanks

Comment: You should search the site for how to do that. There are too many methods to answer that.